# jquery prevent duplicate function assigned

Tags: jquery, function, dynamic, click

If I need to assign a click function dynamically, is there a way to ensure the click function is only assigned once and not duplicated?

```
this.click(function(){
    alert('test');
})
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can unbind the click event before you bind it again, that way you will only have one event attached to it:

```
//assuming this is a jquery object.
this.unbind("click");
this.click(function(){
  alert("clicked once");
});
```

As of jQuery 1.7, click now uses .on (http://api.jquery.com/click/) so the correct code is now

```
//assuming this is a jquery object.
this.off("click");
this.click(function(){
  alert("clicked once");
});
```

This will unbind all click events (including ones created by any plugins you might be using).  To make sure you only unbind your event use namespaces.  (http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
//assuming this is a jquery object.
this.off("click.myApp");
this.on("click.myApp", function(){
  alert("clicked once");
});
```

Here myApp is the namespace.

Comment: Perfect, does exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this did the job. But to be in this situation where I need to do this work around, does this mean that there is a problem with my design? or this is a normal problem that always happens when manipulating DOM with Ajax?

Answer (score 16):

With jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can do something like that:

```
//removes all binding to click for the namespace "myNamespace"
$(document).off('click.myNamespace'); 

$(document).on('click.myNamespace', '.selector', function(event) {...}); 

//this will be also removed (same namespace)
$(document).on('click.myNamespace', '.anotherSelector', function(event) {...});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, sieppl. Just checked the jQuery documentation and it states:
`As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().`
My conclusion: for most cases it is better than .bind()

Comment: @esco_: Yes, I switched to on() completely. I never used bind() though, but stopped using live() and delegate().

Answer (score 9):

I would like to add to Marius's answer--

In avoiding duplicate bindings you don't want to accidentally unbind something if there is supposed to be more than one function bound to an event. This is especially important when you are working on something with multiple developers. To prevent this you can use event namespacing:

```
//assuming this is a jquery object.
var alertEvent = 'click.alert'
this.unbind(alertEvent).bind(alertEvent,function(){
  alert('clicked once');
});
```

Here 'alert' is the name of the namespace for your click event and only your functions that were bound with that namespace will be unbound.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me !

```
$('.element').on('click', function (event) {
    if(event.isDefaultPrevented()) return;
    event.preventDefault();

    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that elements are being added to the html and you want to add an event only for elements added:

```
function addEvents2Elements()//prevent Duplicate
{
    //this will add the event to all elements of class="ele2addevent"
    $('.ele2addevent').not('.clickbind').on('click',function(){alert('once');})

    //this will add a class an then the class="ele2addevent clickbind"
    $('.ele2addevent').not('.clickbind').addClass('.clickbind');
    //all elements of class="... clickbind" will not be catched anymore in the first line because of .not() every time you call this function
}
addEvents2Elements();
```

be shure that you add only with the class="ele2addevent", because after the bind it will be class="ele2addevent clickbind" and not catched again...

Answer (score 0):

Remove existing click event:

```
$('body').off('click','.switch-tab');
```

Add new click event:

```
$('body').on('click','.switch-tab', function () {
   switch_tab($(this).data('tab_id'));
});
```