# How to fix: Ajax - Post request running multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-post

I have a table (formatted with Datatables script) and it has a column which contain few icons to manage actions. When user click on an icon, it load a modal and get the modal content using POST method.

Modal has a save button to complete the action after user make their choice. When they click save button, another post script complete the request and feedback to user.

This process working fine when the first time user load the page. There is a refresh button on the page which can reload the TABLE without reload the PAGE.

If user use this button to refresh the page and try above action. it open the modal and Save button trigger the post action 2 times. If the user refresh the page (using the refresh button) again and try one of the action icons, post script run 3 times... in other words if you refresh 10 times post script run 10 times...

if user use the browser refresh button, we don't get this repetition.

Just wondering whether we can fix this without get rid of the refresh button.

We tried different ways to place the script within the page. but still cannot understand what is triggering the multiple post request.

//javascript
//step 1 - load the modal with an action list

```
$("#proj_data tbody").on("click", ".update_job_progress", function () {
    var pn = $(this).attr('mypn');
    $.post('reports_job_progress.php', {proj: pn}, function (data) {

        $('<div id="progress_update_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"></div>').appendTo('#modal-container').html(data).modal();
    });
});
```

//step 2 - save user choice

```
$('body #modal-container').on('click', '.btn_jobaction', function () {

    var pn = $("#pn").val();
    $.post("reports_job_progress_backend.php", $("#progress_list").serialize(),
            function (res) {
                if (res === 0) {
                    alert("There is a problem saving the information. please try again");

                } else {
                    $("#prog" + pn).html(res);
                    $("#progress_update_modal").modal('hide');
                }
            }
    );

});
```

//step 3 - destroy the modal

```
$("body").on("hidden.bs.modal", ".modal", function () {

    $("#modal-container").empty();
});
```

Could you please help me to understand the issue with this code?

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558377/jquery-prevent-duplicate-function-assigned. it's a similar idea, you are duplicating your onclick.  You should remove it and reset it, probably on a successful response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery prevent duplicate function assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558377/jquery-prevent-duplicate-function-assigned)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is being caused by binding multiple onclick handlers to the element. Please try using `off` like this  `$("#proj_data tbody").off("click").on("click", ...` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: This fixed the problem with repetition. now it created another issue. like i mentioned there are few icons on the table to manage actions. Now modal load only for the last icon (on the script section this is the last bit). If i comment this, then the previous icon can load the modal. it seems something preventing modals except for the icon on click call at the end of script.

Comment: .off() fixed the repetitions issue but it create another problem. eg: if I click icon 1 > modal 1 load > change data -> save submit modal 1 form., then click icon 2 -> it opens modal 2 -> i can edit the data -> but save button not work. i guess this is because of .off()? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@buffy solution worked. However just adding .off('click') was disabling other icons click event as all icons share the same class. after playing with the code i found adding $(this).off('click') does the trick. Now everything working perfect. Thanks @buffy for providing correct directions.

Answer (score -1):

You will bind the click event multiple times. You could either reset the callback, check if the callback has been set or (much better) set the click listener in a part of your script, that will not be executed, whenever you refresh your page (with the mentioned refresh button) like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('body #modal-container').on('click', ...
     $('body #modal-container').on('click', ...
});
```